# Grails Calendar plugin throws stack / recursion error

Tags: grails, plugins, calendar, jscalendar

Calendar plugin version :CURRENT RELEASE    1.2.1

I followed steps as mentioned in the grails plugin documentation, I get the following error in all types of browser

Chrome 14.0835: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum Callstack size exceeded.

Firefox 6.02: Too much recursion calendar.js line 1851

IE 9: Out of stack space calendar.js line 1850

Answer (score 4):

The offending jscalendar code is this:

```
Date.prototype.__msh_oldSetFullYear = Date.prototype.setFullYear;
Date.prototype.setFullYear = function(y) {
    var d = new Date(this);
    d.__msh_oldSetFullYear(y);
    if (d.getMonth() != this.getMonth())
        this.setDate(28);
    this.__msh_oldSetFullYear(y);
};
```

Which redefines `Date.setFullYear()`. Have a look at comments #124 and #125 on this ["old jscalendar" page](http://www.dynarch.com/projects/calendar/old/).

**Comment #124 (by Chris Lively)**

*Suggests updating calendar.js (near the bottom, ~line 1850).*

> For those getting the recursion error. You just need to comment a few
>   lines. See below.
>
> ```
> //Date.prototype.msh_oldSetFullYear = Date.prototype.setFullYear;
> Date.prototype.setFullYear = function(y) {
>     var d = new Date(this);
>     //d.msh_oldSetFullYear(y);
>     if (d.getMonth() != this.getMonth())
>         this.setDate(28);
>     //this._msholdSetFullYear(y);
> };
> ```

**Comment #125 (reply by larisa)**

> The problem with recursion occurs due to multiple includes of calendar
>   JavaScript on a page. As a result Date patch redefines setFullYear
>   function twice and causes infinite loop when it gets executed. We
>   fixed it by making sure that function is redefined only once:
>
> ```
> if(Date.prototype.msh_oldSetFullYear == null) {
>     Date.prototype.msh_oldSetFullYear = Date.prototype.setFullYear;
> }
> ```

Both of these suggest updates to calendar.js, which isn't ideal since it's delivered with the plugin.

Two suggestions:

- Make sure you're not importing the calendar resources twice. Do you have a `<calendar:resources/>` in your main layout *and* your view GSP? If so, remove one of them.
- If that doesn't work, perhaps use a different plugin. The calendar plugin looks like it hasn't been updated in a while (it's using an older version of jscalendar). If you're feeling ambitious, you could go update the plugin yourself!

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me to the right place. As you said I have made changes directly in the calendar.js in the plugin and tested. Its working fine. But since you also pointed out that its not ideal to touch the plugin files, I need to look for an appropriate way of changing it.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
if (Date.prototype.__msh_oldSetFullYear == null) {
    Date.prototype.__msh_oldSetFullYear = Date.prototype.setFullYear;
}
Date.prototype.setFullYear = function(y) {
    var d = new Date(this);
    Date.prototype.__msh_oldSetFullYear.apply(d, arguments);
    if (d.getMonth() != this.getMonth())
        this.setDate(28);
    Date.prototype.__msh_oldSetFullYear.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I resolved this issue is

1) Downloaded the source of the plugin
2) Created a plugin with the same name locally.
3) Copied the original source files to the local plugin I created
4) Changed the javascript file as suggested above
5) Compile and package the plugin
6) Removed the old plugin in my main project
7) Installed the newly created plugin from the zip file created from step 5.

It worked like a charm.

Thanks Rob Hruska for pointing me where to comment in the javascript file

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue, I had placed `<calendar:resources/>` in my main jsp as well as in the template which was rendered in the jsp. Removing one of them solved the issue.